# Allpro adapter and Arduino - UART

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, uart, voltage-divider

I couldn't find for [allpro obd uart](http://www.obddiag.net/allpro.html) if the RX pin should receive 3.3v or 5v from Arduino TX pin (since the Arduino will send 5v by default without voltage divider), so I was wondering if someone can help figuring that out.

I was looking datasheet for that microchip LCP15XX which is used on the board, and to me it looks it should be 3.3v but not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schematic at your link seems to show the receive signal connected to pin 22, PIO_14.  Oddly enough this *does not* appear to be a hardware UART pin, but it is also one of the many pins on that device that is specified as being 5v tolerant under certain circumstances.

So it looks like the design *could have been* done in such a way that a 5v input would be permissible, however if you do not want to take the time to verify that you can play it safer with a 3.3v input.

Keep in mind that neither 3.3v input nor 5v input is acceptable if the chip is not powered.

Answer (score 1):

The LPC1517 is definitely 3.3V (or rather, it can be 2.4V to 3.6V, but they will have chosen 3.3V)

Comment: These are supply voltages, not input voltages.

Comment: While this is true, it does mean that the circuit will work on 3.3V, so theres no need to risk 5V (assuming that the pins are directly connected to the LPC). The datasheet for the LPC is not amazingly helpful in terms of pin voltage limits, but it doesnt explicitly say 5V tolerant, which is something they would probably put in the features section if it were the case.
edit: reply to a deleted comment

Comment: You might want to have another look at that data sheet.

Comment: Can you be more specific? it is >700 pages long. They are supply voltages, but microcontrollers tend to want their pin logic voltages to be the same as their supply voltages.

Comment: Unless they are designed for a wider range, which many of those on this chip including the one apparently in question have an explicit note to such effect attached.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. Are you saying that this chip definitely is 5V tolerant? If so, where specifically does it say this?

Comment: Search the data sheet for "tolerant" and you will find where it describes the conditions under which many of the I/O pins are, and the notes indicating which those are.

Comment: Ah right, I didn't see that the OBD had a schematic attached. Nevertheless, I would definitely suggest using the known safe voltage, which is 3.3V. One way to verify what voltage would definitely work for it is to see at what voltage it sends out information on the tx pin (assuming it will do so without receiving anything, which it might not).